# NixOS Set python script as login shell

Tags: python, shell, nixos

I am writing a NixOS config for my server and I want to disable all root access except from a special user which can only run my python script. I want to set the login shell of the user to my python script because I disabled bash for the user.

I tried setting `users.users.pyadm.shell = "python3 /usr/local/share/pyadm/main.py"`, but I got a type error.

Comment: Use one of the trivial builder types to embed that command in a wrapper. And specify the specific interpreter with its dependencies, don't pull it from the PATH.

Comment: (why are you using `/usr/local/share` in NixOS in the first place? If you're doing this right, your script will be wrapped in a derivation, and thus resolved to a store path automatically; that also has the effect of letting you roll back to an old version of the administration script when you choose an old system state from the bootloader menu, so a bug in the script doesn't leave your system unmaintainable)